# laravel 8x how to set route edit form datatable

Tags: laravel-8

Controller:

```
public function getStudents(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {


            $data = DB::table('labors_address')
            ->leftJoin('labour', 'labors_address.labour_id', '=', 'labour.labour_id')
            ->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $actionBtn = '<a href="{{route("labors.form-edit")}}'.$row->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>';
                    return $actionBtn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/labors-address-edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\LaborsAddressController::class, 'edit'])->name('labors.form-edit');
```

Page error:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7Broute(
```

Comment: `return $actionBtn;` will return just a string, no Blade parsing `{{route(...)}}`is done on that string.

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get('/labors-address-edit/{id}',
    [App\Http\Controllers\LaborsAddressController::class, 'edit']
)->name('labors.form-edit');
```